# variable becomes empty in callback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created a thread in `Global.asax` of asp.net. The thread store a value in variable name `downloadnos` and use a library that start a new thread and receive a callback method. When the callback method is called, I try to read the variable, but it is empty. Why is it so? How to fix this?

Comment: Can we see some code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the variable static might help.

Comment: That is something you should almost never do in asp.net. You usually have better alternatives, depending on context, like `Application`, `Session`, `ViewState` (for web forms), etc.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want the variable to last the length of your web server running? if so use Application to store the data.  That is:

Application["mydata"] = "mydatatosave"